# widget exclude post by custom field

Tags: widgets, exclude, meta-value

I have a widget that gets posts from different post_type's.
I want to exclude some posts that have a custom field value

e.g.
I save a form where a checkbox adds a value of 0 or 1 depending if ticked.
If the value is 0 the post should be visable and if the value is 1 then it should not be visable.

Here is what I have to extract the posts:

```
$wpcust = new WP_Query( 
array( 
'post_type' => array(
    'posts_type_1',
    'posts_type_2'
    ),   
'showposts' => '4' ) 
);
```

This is a basic WP_Query that selects posts based on two post_types.
What I want to add is:

```
'meta_key' => 'key',
'meta_value' => 'value'
```

Where value is 0 or 1.
If I do this it only shows posts based on the meta_value.
I need it the other way around where this excludes those posts.

Any help?
Thnx

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `meta_query` parameter in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) allows you to query posts that don't have a certain custom field. Furthermore, you can check for multiple custom fields. With two queries in `meta_query`, you can fetch all posts that either don't have a custom field, or have it set to 0:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'my-key',
        'value' => '0'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'my-key',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'value' => 'Use any value here' // If you're using WordPress 3.9+, you can omit "value" for NOT EXISTS
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow, That.was.awesome Thnx so much and so quick.... Nice.